# Paginating with SQL ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql

I want to return search results in paginated format. However I can't seem to successfully get the first 10 results of my query.

The problem is the 'RowNum' returned are like 405, 687, 1024 etc. I want them to be renumbered as 1,2,3,4,5 etc., so that when I specify between rows 1 and 20 i get the first 20 search results. Instead, because the numbers are larger, I get no results between 1 and 10.

If i change RowNum condition to:

```
AND RowNum < 20000
```

I get plenty of results

Here's the sql:

```
                SELECT  *
            FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY DocumentID ) AS RowNum, *
                      FROM      Table
                    ) AS RowConstrainedResult
            WHERE   RowNum >= 1
                AND RowNum < 20
                                AND Title LIKE '%diabetes%'
                                AND Title LIKE '%risk%'
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the `WHERE` in the sub query. I would use a CTE instead (assuming SQL-Server)::

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT  T.*, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY DocumentID ) AS RowNum
  FROM Table T
  WHERE Title LIKE '%diabetes%' AND Title LIKE '%risk%'
)
SELECT * FROM CTE 
WHERE RowNum >= 1 AND RowNum < 20
```

Comment: Brilliant, I've been stuck on this for hours, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your `where` condition into the subquery:

```
       SELECT  *
        FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY DocumentID ) AS RowNum, *
                  FROM      Table
                  where  Title LIKE '%diabetes%'
                            AND Title LIKE '%risk%'
                ) AS RowConstrainedResult
        WHERE   RowNum >= 1 AND RowNum < 20
```

The`rownum` vairable is being assign sequentially to all rows.  You are not selecting any in the top 20.