# Trying to select a range.. for instance 10-20 of top results

Tags: sql, sql-server

ive googled and searched this site and nothing seems to work, seems like it doesn't like the syntax from everything i found.. seems pretty simple though so it's getting frustrating.  can anyone help?  would like it to use the topRange and bottomRange variables I've created

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getTopFantasyPlayersByPositionSeason]
    @top int,
    @position varchar(3),
    @topRange int,
    @bottomRange int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    IF @position = 'QB' OR @position = 'RB' OR @position = 'WR' OR @position = 'TE' OR @position = 'K' OR @position = 'D' OR @position = 'TE'
        BEGIN
            SELECT TOP (@top) *
            FROM nflPassers_season
            WHERE position=@position AND points > 0
            ORDER BY points DESC
        END

END
```

Comment: Where do you want to use it? You have not the value of both the variables either!!

Comment: the variables are inputted by the user.. hope that helps in what you're asking?

Comment: But what you want to achieve from these variables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paginating with SQL ROW\_NUMBER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728391/paginating-with-sql-row-number)

Comment: i want to be able to be like.. say toprange = 10, bottomrange = 20.. it'll select the top 10 through 20 players by points

Comment: k i'll check it out mbeckish, like i said i've tried searching here and nothing worked so far (for the negative voters)

Comment: Which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: 2008 microsoft sql server Goat

Comment: mbeckish tried those solutions and they aren't working for me.

Comment: @user1189352 - The linked solution is the same as the one you accepted - basically, use ROW_NUMBER()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic pagination pre-SQL 2012:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY points DESC) AS RowRank
      FROM YourTable
      )AS sub
WHERE Rowrank BETWEEN @Variable1 AND @Variable2
```

If you want a range of results per some grouping, ie by player, you can add `PARTITION BY` to the `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SomeField ORDER BY points DESC) AS RowRank
      FROM YourTable
      WHERE position = @position
        AND points > 0
      ) AS sub
WHERE Rowrank BETWEEN @Variable1 AND @Variable2
```

That would make the ranking begin at 1 for each item in the `PARTITION BY` clause.

Comment: ah didn't know the term pagination...if i did probably would've found the answer easier =\  thanks will try this

Comment: the words "sub", "Rowrank" are getting errors.. not a SQL guy sorry.. what would i put there?

Comment: Those are just aliases, try `AS RowRank` and `AS sub` instead.

Comment: got it to run and it worked.. but i need to have the position and points check.. i tried implementing it as WHERE RowRank BETWEEN topRange AND bottomRange AND position=position AND points > 0, but it's coming up blank now for some reason.. hm  (had to remove the @ symbol)

Comment: Perhaps include the other `WHERE` criteria on the inside query.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getTopFantasyPlayersByPositionSeason]
    @top INT
  , @position VARCHAR(3)
  , @topRange INT
  , @bottomRange INT
AS 
    BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
        IF @position IN ( 'QB', 'RB', 'WR', 'TE', 'K', 'D', 'TE' ) 
            BEGIN
            ;
                WITH    c AS ( SELECT   rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY points DESC)
                                      , firstname
                               FROM     nflPassers_season
                               WHERE    position = @position
                                        AND points > 0
                             )
                    SELECT  firstname
                    FROM    c
                    WHERE   rn BETWEEN @toprange AND @bottomRange

            END

    END
```

Comment: hey stuart, what would i put in replacement under column_list if you say to not use it in your production code?

Comment: the list of columns that you want to return from your table (e.g., ID, player_name, etc...)

Comment: really would like to use this if i knew what to put in replacement for column_list as it errors?  (ya i know you said not to put in production code.. so then what do i put?)

Comment: just saw your answer, will try and get back to you

Comment: what are the names of the columns from your nflPlayers_season table?  that's what I mean by column list.  Use the names from your table instead of an asterisk.

Comment: i tried it and replaced column_list with my "firstName" column.. and it's not coming up with the correct results unfortunately =\